# Getting index of two repeated numbers on a list python

Tags: python, list, indexing

How to get the index values for two numbers repeated on a list?

I basically need this:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a.XindexX(2)
1, 6
```

So there I am getting the index numbers of the two `2` values in the list?

Comment: There might be 2 1s or 2 2s. Which do you want?

Comment: Yeah sorry for the bad indices. My Bad! And I just need to know the indices of the numbers that are repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` and a list comprehension.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == 2]
[1, 6]
```

Now to make a function that does this:

```
def findMatchIndexes(myList, element):
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(myList) if x == element]
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted (twice!); it's the correct answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank You Very Much! :) // BTW I dont see any downvote on the answer! EDIT, It was on the Question. Not on your answer. :/

Answer (score 1):

Another version using `index` method of `list` (and better exception handling maybe):

```
def match_indexs(a, x):
    out = []
    if x in a:
        out.append(a.index(x))
        for i in range(a.count(x) - 1):
            out.append(a.index(x, out[-1] + 1))
    return out

a=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5, 6]
print(match_indexs(a, 2))
print(match_indexs(a, 6))
print(match_indexs(a, 7))
```

Output:

```
$ python count.py 
[1, 6]
[10]
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Too late to be considered but I'm going to post it anyway... 
Using a generator might be a better option if the origin sequence is too big for working memory... 
Nothing special to see here..

```
def get_indices(l,x):
    for i,j in enumerate (l):
        if j == x: yield i


numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
fx = get_indices(numbers,2)
print list(fx)
```